# best approach to get input string and map it to a constant and use the constant c#

Tags: c#, cucumber, constants

I have a string which is input from a cucumber feature step and the corresponding string's constant value should be used in further code

Example:

I have a input string "region1" -it can be "Region1" as well

I need to map it to a list of constants as that list won't change:

`const regions = { region1="US", region2="IND", region3="UK" };`

and get something like getData(region1.value)

What is best practice? Constants or just list or enum?

Comment: I'd [parse to enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-5.0).

Comment: You cannot create consts at runtime - they are constant as they are baked into the application at compilation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a easy way.
In the "load" functions in your form yo can create a array (or list or Map) with al controls the same functionatity. And work with this list is more easy.
Even more, you can create functions like "GetRegionValue(int index)".
I am not sure if you are looking a solution like this...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [dictionary](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary). It's the easiest way to go with your needs.
Here are some examples how you can use it for your needs (if I got you right)

```
Dictionary<string,string> regions = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
  {"REGION1","US"},{"REGION2","UK"}...
};
foreach(var region in regions)
{
  if(inputString.Equals(region.Key.ToUpper()))
    //do something
}
--
public string GetData(string searchString){
  string returnData = "";
  if(regions.ContainsKey(searchString.ToUpper()))
    returnData = regions[searchString.Toupper()];
  return returnData;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).